# How to float these C3 chart and HandsOnTable elements without impacting features?

Tags: css-float, jsfiddle, handsontable, c3.js

I have a HandsOnTable table (with a couple of additions for user-requests) and a C3 chart (which needs to fill horizontal space) and can't get them living alongside each other nicely.

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/2vc606wx/13/

I /think/ these two DIVs should be able to be floated, but when I do they either don't (float) or stop the tooltip of the C3 chart OR stop some of the middle column editing from working:

```
  <div>
    <table class="tgh"><tr><td>Auxilliary Power</td></tr></table>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <table class="tg">
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-yw4l" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="c3chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I did this, but I'm pretty sure it's a bodge:

https://jsfiddle.net/horacebury/2vc606wx/15/

```
<div style="float: right;">
  <table class="tgh">
    <tr>
      <td>Auxilliary Power</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="example"></div>
  <table class="tg">
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-yw4l" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="c3chart" style="width: 65%;"></div>
```